# Is it possible to implement AbstractList for a specific rather than generic type?

Tags: java, list, abstract

Is it possible to implement AbstractList in such a way that it can only hold objects of a certain type?

Comment: By implement I assume you mean extend. If this a curiosity question or is there a particular reason you don't want to use one of the already existing List implementations?

Comment: I am writing an application front end for a database. For the sake of abstraction, I want to create a list that holds only a certain type of objects, and has special operations that act on those objects. For instances, A MarketList to hold objects of type Market, a DeviceList to hold objects of type Device, etc..

Comment: If you do not need to change the base behavior of a list, then I would recommend instead creating controller classes for each one of your object types (like MarketController, DeviceController etc), where these controllers *then* hold onto `List<Market`, `List<Device>`, internally.

Comment: That is a good thought. Can you explain further why that is a better idea?

Comment: In general you should favor composition over inheritance. Because often, in OOP, a class is actually *several* kinds of things. When you constrain it to inherit from a class you are defining it to be *just the one thing*. In general, composition is significantly more flexible than inheritance.

Comment: If you need or want that flexibility, this is fine.  If your problem and application call for a MarketList, then make that.  Randomly inserting flexibility into programming increases complexity -- witness the extra "Controller" concept introduced in this example -- so you should use it only in a case where it is worth the complexity.

Comment: @rcook - such reckless statements is what led to such disastrous classes like the `Properties` API. Complexity for complexities sake is bad, but over-simplification is just as bad or worse.

Comment: @Perception So considering which technique is best in one case is "over-simplification"?  You always favor "composition over inheritance"?  But that's "complexity for complexity's sake", isn't it?

Comment: @rcook - I believe my words were 'in general', not 'always'. You might want to read up more on the topic [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=effective+java+composition+over+inheritance&source=bl&ots=yYIiOiv5M4&sig=GK8wxK5u1cGKi0vOPFw7fbbWeuE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KaFHUYu5FM3E4AOhkYCoBg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20composition%20over%20inheritance&f=false). The concepts are quite a bit much to fit into a couple of comments on StackOverflow.

Comment: You said "In general", but the mere suggestion to consider an alternative, without even an assertion that it was better, leads to colorful descriptive words like "reckless" and "disastrous".  Your arguments are inconsistent, as though you *read* about a principle and now advocate it without understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

```
class FooList extends AbstractList<Foo> {
  ...
}
```